# Hide events where event start_time < Time.now in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have an app where users can generate events based on a date and time they select.  For these I used: `t.date :event_date` and `t.time :start_time` to store the data in my database (MySql in development and Postgres in production).  I used both of these types because I was able to find a convenient bootstrap styled datepicker and timepicker that looked good.  The problem I have now though, is on my events index page. I want to limit the feed to events where the time has yet to pass.  That is, I want to hide events that have happened in the past.  I was able to restrict the date fairly easily with this in my controller:

```
def index
  @events = Event.where('start_date >= ?', 
  Date.today).order("start_date ASC", "start_time ASC").paginate(page: 
  params[:page], per_page: 5)
end
```

But because the time column is formatted beginning at the year 2000 I am unable to think of a way to limit the events based upon time as well.  The time zone isn't much of an issue as I anticipate the app to only be used locally.

Comment: Can you change the schema to use a single timestamp column? You can always combine the two values in your controllers (or models) if you want to stay with the UI widgets you're using. I bring this up because a `time` column inside PostgreSQL will be just a time-of-day but there is no time-of-day class in Ruby so ActiveRecord uses the same class that it uses for timestamps (hence the odd appearance of 2000). `time` makes perfect sense inside the database but they're cumbersome to work with in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a string for time would work.
You can add a new format in your locale file to use with this query:

```
time:
formats:
  time: "%I:%M:%S"
```

And then:

```
@events = Event.where('start_date >= ? AND start_time > ?', Date.today, I18n.l(Time.now, format: :time))
```

That said, the commenter is right, time columns in Rails are a bit of a hassle to work with.